# "such a day" or "such day"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, indefinite-articles

> It's such a nice day today!

I'm interested in the usage of the indefinite article. I know this sentence is correct. We use an indefinite article in exclamations with countable nouns.

But the question is: If it's NOT an exclamation, what do we use? Let's say:

1. I went for a walk because it was such a wonderful day.
2. I went for a walk because it was a such wonderful day.
3. I went for a walk because it was such wonderful day.

Which variant is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I went for a walk because it was such a wonderful day.

is correct.

Comment: thanks a lot! I honestly hoped there wouldn't be any articles.

Answer (score 10):

The first is correct:

> …it was **such a wonderful day**.

The others are **not** correct.  Generally, when used with a singular countable noun, *such* should come before the indefinite article, like your example:

> It was such a wonderful day.

When used with a plural noun, or an uncountable noun, then there’s no article, but it should still precede any adjectives (and there should usually be some adjective(s); without an adjective, this use is generally somewhat poetic/archaic):

> He sings such beautiful songs!  She listens to such horrible music.  There was such merriment at the party last night…

It should never follow *a*, or be used with *the*; all the following are wrong:

> *…a such wonderful day…       *…the such wonderful day…       *…such the wonderful day…

Comment: I think you mean "precede" rather than "proceed"

Comment: thanks. Your answer is very full. Now I understand that there's no difference whether this is an exclamation or not, whether there is the word "such" or not, the rules of using an article are the same.

Comment: @Colin Fine:  Ack!  Colour me mortified!  Thankyou…

Answer (score 2):

When using **such** with a singular noun, put such before 'a'. This is a general rule.

Examples:

> She's **such a lovely person** (*NOT a such lovely person*).
>
> I doubt if **such a promise** has any value.